# Return each matching selected option and appendTo ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop over different `select` elements, check the value, if it matches find the `next() textarea` value and `appendTo` a summary `div`.

I am using the `change event` but I am always getting `Cannot read property 'appendTo' of undefined`

```
(function () {
  var $summary = $('#summary');
  var testSelect = function () {
    $('select option:selected').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "NC") {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                // do nothing
            } else {
                $(this).find('textarea').val().appendTo($summary);
            }
        }
    });
}

window.addEventListener('change', testSelect, false);
})();
```

Does this mean my `$summary` is undefined

Comment: Provide jsFiddle for get quick answer.

Comment: You logic is flawed, if `val == NC` hits, how can `val == ''` be true?

Comment: @Sadikhasan Stack Overflow introduced Code Snippets a while back. You should ideally recommend using one of those over an external site.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Some users dont know how to use `Code  Snippest` that's why.

Comment: you should not be doing "appendTo" in val()'s return, since it will return a "primitive" type, and not a jquery object

Comment: @Sadikhasan If that is the case then you should perhaps raise that as an issue on http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I know how to use `Code Snippest` but new user do not know how to use `Code Snippest` even how `code format` in stackoverflow.

Comment: Fiddle added http://jsfiddle.net/StudentRik/Lkxukj1k/